# Process Millions of DB records in concurrently in batch using grails

Tags: mysql, grails, concurrency

I need help in processing millions of db records using grails.

I have millions of records in db. I cant fetch all the records in single query as it will throw out of memory exception. So I want to fetch records in batches. And process each record of every batch. 
I want to have Blocking Queue kind of implementation in grails where I will add results of all sub queries in the queue and then multiple threads will consume the queue and do their own processing.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be exactly an efficient solution you want but , using a 
`bootstarp.groovy` file i have handles similar issue like reading from excel file and adding it into a database each record fetching line by line using threads.

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional;
```

`BootStrap.groovy`

```
@Transactional
def importformExcel(){

// add you code here for batching...and call it inside the thread
}
```

Add the following code inside the `bootstrap.init` section to execute it on start up .You can add some logic to prevent every time running or make it once executed and stop forever.

```
  def init = { servletContext ->

        sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
        try{
                    @Transactional
                    Thread stateLgaThread = new Thread({

                     //code ur thread logic here!
                     importformExcel()
                     //sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
                     TimerThread.sleep(100) // even give more chance to other application/instruction
                     } as Runnable).start()
                     @Transactional
                     Thread regionThread = new Thread({
                        //code ur thread logic here!
                        importformExcel()
                        // sessionFactory.currentSession.flush()
                         TimerThread.sleep(100) // even give more chance to other application/instruction
                     } as Runnable).start()
                }
                catch(ex){

                    log.debug "Inside Thread Exception:{ex.message}"
                }

}
```